A program to solve quadratic equations
Referring to the exercise in chapter 4 number 18 of Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ which asks:

Write a program to solve quadratic equations. A quadratic equation is of the form
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $$
If you don’t know the quadratic formula for solving such an expression, do some research. Remember, researching how
to solve a problem is often necessary before a programmer can teach the computer how to solve it. Use doubles for the user inputs for a, b, and c. Since there are two solutions to a quadratic equation, output both x₁ and x₂.

I wrote as follows:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

    // This program solve quadratic equation on the form ax2 + bx + c = 0

bool quadraticEquation(double &x1, double &x2, double a, double b, double c)
{
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    
    if (delta > 0) 
    {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



   
int main()
{             


    std::cout << "This program solves quadratic equations in the form ax2 + bx + c = 0\n\n";
    std::cout << "Enter a value for a b and c than press enter.\n\n";


    double a, b, c, x1, x2;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;


    if (quadraticEquation(x1, x2, a, b, c))
    {
        std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
        std::cout << "x2 = " << x2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe equation has no real roots or is monomoic.\n";
    }
}


Using references as return values ​​would theoretically have gone beyond the arguments of the text. What do you think? Feel free to use this as an example of how programs should NOT be written.

What's "monomoic" in that last message mean?  I couldn't find a definition anywhere, and can't even guess its meaning.

means with only one monomial, like 4X2 = 0,
x1 and x2 are both 0.

Oh, a solution with a single root?  I hadn't heard that term for it before.  Thanks for the explanation.

Me neither, honestly, I did them many years ago...but i tested the various cases including pure equation (ax2-1=0), spurious equation (ax2+bx=0) and this monomial equation that says for every monomial equation
ax2=0 which always has a unique solution: x1=x2=0.

What if a is 0?

Why ask whether delta is strictly greater than 0 rather than whether delta is greater than or equal to 0?

@Michael Hardy: you're right, the algorithm requires this condition to find all the solutions, including x1 and x2 coinciding, i.e. discriminant = 0.
Initially I thought of distinguishing the three delta cases individually , but it's right to put delta > or = 0 to have all the cases. In that case from the result "The equation has no real roots or is monomoic" must be removed "..or is monomoic". This would solve the result X1 = X2 = 0.  Good observation!

@md2perpe:  second degree equation written in the form ax2+bx+c=0 with coefficients a, b and c real with  a ≠ 0. If you look carefully it would not be a second degree equation with a = 0. At first glance the limiting case is that ax2 = 0 with b and c equal to 0 i.e. monomoic.

I know that it won't be a proper second degree equation if a=0, but why not cover that case too?

@md2perpe: I tried to see if it covered the specific case and the particular cases of pure, spurious and monomial. In fact there is no case that predicts a≠0. In any case you could consider it as off-topic cases with error messages. But it was not in the purpose of the exercise I think

If it's not in the purpose of the exercise to solve equations where a=0, then I think that you should report that as invalid input.

When googling for "monomoic" I get 14 results. Fourteen. I don't think anyone uses the word in this sense.

don't worry I think it was an edge case exposed by the text I was reading. but try look for monomial :D

Note that I am a mathematician, not a programmer of any type (though I did take a year of numerical analysis in grad school, so I have experience solving problems like this with code—it just isn't what I typically do in my day-to-day).  My comments are directed at fixing more mathematical issues.
Missing Case: \$\Delta = 0\$
The given code returns false if either (a) the roots are complex, nonreal, and (b) if there is a double root.  The code seems to be intentional about missing complex roots (i.e. it seems like it is meant to complain if the discriminant is not zero), but it fails to correctly return real roots in the case of a double root, and will often incorrectly assert that a polynomial is "monomoic" (a word I have never heard before, by the way).  This corresponds to the case when \$\Delta = 0\$.  If \$\Delta = 0\$, then the roots are
$$ x_1 = x_2 = \frac{-b}{2a}. $$
Note that, contrary to the claim made in the comments below the question, this is not simply the case that the equation reduces to \$ax^2 = 0\$.  For example, the quadratic polynomial
$$ p(x) = x^2 - 6x + 9 $$
has discriminant zero, but has solutions \$x_1=x_2=3\$.
Catastrophic Cancellation / Loss of Precision
When taking the difference of two numbers that are close to each other, it is possible to introduce large (relative) errors, depending on how those original numbers have been rounded and how the difference is rounded (and note that rounding will happen when doing floating point arithmetic).  There is a reasonable discussion of this phenomenon on Wikipedia.  When solving quadratic equations of the form \$ax^2 + bx + c = 0\$, it is very possible for \$-b\$ to be approximately the same magnitude as \$\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\$ (specifically, if \$4ac\$ is relatively small when compared to \$b^2\$, this is what will happen).  This can lead to catastrophic cancellation when computing \$-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}\$ (if \$b > 0\$, then the addition can cause problems; if \$b<0\$, then the subtraction can cause problems).
The fix is to ensure that two numbers of approximately the same magnitude are not being subtracted.  In the case of the quadratic formula, "rationalizing the numerator" leads to
$$ 
\begin{align} \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} 
&= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \cdot \frac{-b\mp \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4ac}} \\ 
&= \frac{b^2 - (b^2-4ac)}{-2a\left(b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\right)} \\ 
&= \frac{2c}{b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}. 
\end{align} 
$$
This gives two cases:

If \$b > 0\$, then define
$$ x_1 = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \qquad\text{and}\qquad x_2 = \frac{2c}{b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}. $$

If \$b < 0\$, then define
$$ x_1 = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \qquad\text{and}\qquad x_2 = \frac{2c}{b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}. $$


Note that, in both cases, the expressions reduce to adding terms which have the same sign, which mitigates against catastrophic cancellation.

Missing Case: Δ=0. You are absolutely right, at least the discriminant must be set > or = 0 in that case it also covered x1=x2=0 i.e. monomoic. So I should have left "The equation has no real roots" with delta less than zero

@RedM3tal Again, something which you need to be very clear about:  there are non-"monomoic" quadratic polynomials which have discriminant zero.  Indeed, I think that the "monomoic" case is a red herring.  If the discriminant is zero, then there is a double root.  That root could be anything.

@ Xander: ok don't worry. Maybe it was a mistake in the text where I documented myself. I think it meant monomial.  The text has exposed the need to apply the solution formula or the reduction in incomplete equations. But I believe it is an end in itself.. But don't worry you've done a great exposition. TOP when you talk about Catastrophic Cancellation / Loss of Precision. ;)

This is reasonably good beginner code, and it is structured well (decomposition into functions).  I have a few small suggestions.

sqrt should be std::sqrt.  The standard library is allowed, but not required, to additionally define the global namespace symbol, so it makes our code less portable if we depend on that.

Instead of modifying caller's values through references and returning a success/failure indication that could easily be ignored, we can combine all that into the return type:
std::optional<std::pair<double>> solve_quadratic(double a, double b, double c)

or
std::vector<double> solve_quadratic(double a, double b, double c)

The fixed-capacity vector type proposed for C++26 would be even better, given that we know we return a maximum of two values: it is a value type like std::array, so we'd avoid the overhead of dynamic storage.

C++ has complex-number types, so we could extend the program to find roots even if they are not real numbers.  Then we'd simply return a std::pair rather than an optional pair.

We should probably verify that a is non-zero so that we don't divide by it.  If we find it is zero, we could provide an alternative code path that solves the linear equation (unless b is also zero, of course) or we could just throw an exception.

When we read from a stream, we must always test whether it was successful.  We can do that by calling std::cin.exceptions() to cause it to throw on error, or we could simply test it afterwards:
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if (!std::cin) {
        std:cerr << "Failed to read inputs";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;  // include <cstdlib> for this
    }


I'm guessing that endl is meant to be std::endl here:

    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
    std::cout << "x2 = " << x2 << endl;


There's no benefit to forcing a flush of the stream, so I recommend replacing with plain '\n'.

you are right using the author's prepackaged file std_lib_facilities which contains all the header files including the namespaces, if I forget to put std:: it is not reported by VS and in fact I did a half job by putting it only on the cout and the cin...

The program is very simple, it should provide for inserting 0 instead of b or c or both to consider the various special cases. This does not mean that it can be improved and made efficient for practical uses.
Thanks for the advice.

@RedM3tal: One great thing about decomposing into functions is that it gives you opportunity to test the function in isolation.  You might want to read about Unit Tests if you are not already familiar with the practice - I find it very helpful to create tests when I'm writing or modifying code.

Re "the program is very simple", I completely agree.  I need to get better at distinguishing between things that are actual defects (checking result of >>) and things that are just suggestions for improving your C++ knowledge (std::complex, std::optional).

Isn't the fact that his quadraticEquation function is missing a return statement also a problem?

Would suggest the test for valid input be if (std::cin >> a), and so forth. Much simpler.

@Davislor, that's arguable - usually we want to test the negative, for an early exit.  We could write if (!(c >> a >> b >>c)), but that seems quite clumsy to me.  It's all subjective, I guess - the important thing is not to use the variables before we know they have been assigned to.

@Green, that's certainly true - and shows I just skimmed this and didn't feed it to a compiler!

@Green grün 绿色 vert зеленый: in fact the return values ​​are the two arguments double &x1, double &x2. The program compiles fine in VS but you can put a return inside the first if.

@RedM3tal: "compiles fine" is troubling - it suggests you're compiling without enough warnings enabled.  It's a good idea for a compiler to tell you about this because flowing off the end of a function that is neither main nor a coroutine results in undefined behavior.

@Toby Speight: Honestly it wasn't an oversight, I was just thinking about having the return values ​​in the two references. I didn't really think about it; but looking closely, a true return value on the first if in the method was perfect... since the function is then called inside the if else in the main where it expects to receive a true value and not just probably something greater than 0. As for the VS checks and warnings I honestly don't remember disabling anything... the error generation is set to Build Only rather than Build+IntelliSense.

@RedM3tal It's usually encouraged to put a return at the end of every possible execution branch of the method, if you use return.

@Green grün 绿色 vert зеленый: you're right, I hadn't thought of that. Good to know that this could cause problems.

Bug: Check for Divide-by-Zero
Your a could be either +0.0 or -0.0.
Bug: Check for Invalid Input
The simplest way to do this is with tests like if (std::cin >> a).  This will evaluate to false if any error occurred on the stream.
The Return Type
Toby Speight discussed this, but I’d like to address the point in more detail.  Mathematically, there are four possibilities.

The leading coefficient could be +0.0 or -0.0, giving you a lower-degree polynomial. You may want to check for a = 0, b ≠ 0, and solve bx + c = 0 to get x = - c/b.  Alternatively, you could throw a std::domain_error exception.
The discriminant is negative.  There are no real roots.
The discriminant is zero.  There is one real root, with multiplicity two. For example, x**2 returns {0}
The discriminant is positive.  There are two real roots. For example, x**2 - 1 returns {-1, 1}.

Since there could be zero, one or two return values, a std::vector<double> would be a better return type than the alternatives you’ve been given.  You can also iterate over it with a range-based for loop like:
for (const auto x : roots) {

Consider Holding the Coefficients in a std::array
If you work with higher-degree polynomials, you will, at some point, realize you should declare an array for the coefficients, instead of passing them in as individual variables.  One very widely-used representation of a polynomial of degree N is an array where coeffs[i] is the coefficient of xⁱ.  That’s easy to understand and efficient to work with.
For example, it enables a fast algorithm to evaluate a polynomial using multiply-add in a loop.  If your return types, like the coefficients of the polynomial and the set of real roots, are single objects, you also become able to chain and compose your functions, such as:
printRoots(realRoots(readQuadratic(std::cin)));

Naming and Documentation
The function name quadraticEquation tells us nothing about what it does.  It’s not at all obvious from looking at the function signature what the behavior is, whether the reference parameters are outputs only or also inputs, when they are or are not valid results, or which inputs cause it to fail.  Consider writing out a contract, for example:
/* Holds the coefficients of a quadratic polynomial.  Element [i] is the
 * coefficient of x**i.
 */
using Quadratic = std::array<double, 3>;

/* Finds the real roots, if any, of the polynomial with coefficients coeffs.  A
 * root with multiplicity two is returned only once. The lead coefficient,
 * coeffs[2], MUST be non-zero.
 *
 * Throws std::domain_error on invalid input.  Otherwise,
 * Returns a vector containing zero to two real roots, from smallest to largest.
 */
std::vector<double> realRoots(Quadratic coeffs) {

I find it helps my design to think this through and write it out, before I start coding.
One advantage to defining a Quadratic type is that it’s less important for the function name to say that it works on quadratics.  If we ever need to solve linear or cubic equations, we’d just overload realRoots to find the real roots of some other input type.

Good answer. Personally, I would treat a = 0  as an invalid input. Allowing a = 0 allows a = b = c = 0 which has infinite solutions for x. The best design in my opinion would be a helper to solve x^2 + Bx + C = 0 and wrapping some input validation around B = b / a, C = c / a.

@JustinChang If we were using this in HPC, it would be very important that the compiler be able to automatically vectorize this function. So throwing an exception would be right out. We might have it evaluate to NaN?

Sounds reasonable. Or returning no solutions.

The usual computational assessment is to assume a, b, c are without error, even though they very often are derived inexactly.
Discriminant == 0
Mathematically, when b*b == 4*a*c, there is a root with multiplicity of 2.
With floating point math, b*b == 4*a*c may be true yet the math roots
are ever so close to each other (yet distinct).  The discriminant calculation rounds to 0.0.  These 2 math roots may/may not round to the same double.
Since our derived roots experience computational roundings, asserting we have one root with multiplicity of 2 is not really that certain.
Code could use wider math (e.g. more than 2x precision and 2x expo range) and/or a fair amount of detail to floating-point exact flags to achieve a true multiplicity of 2 detection, yet it is not often worth it.

Code could use a different approach to avoid the severe precision cancelation of subtraction.
double ac4 = a*c*4;
if (ac4 > 0) {
  double sqrt_ac4 = std::sqrt(ac4);
  delta = (b + sqrt_ac4)*(b - sqrt_ac4);
} else {
  delta = b*b - ac4;
}

Avoiding -b +/-discriminant cancelation
As suggested elsewhere, choose the sign of the discriminant to increase the magnitude of -b +/-discriminant.  Then the other root is is found via root1*root2 = c/a; with the usual precautions about division by 0.
Sample alternative

This alternative does not resorting to wider math like long double.

// My strength is C code.
// I hope C++ programmers find this easy enough to adjust.
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
 * Return number of roots: 0, 1, 2 or
 * -1 implies infinite number of roots in the case of a=b=c=0.
 */
int quadratic(double _Complex root[2], double a, double b, double c) {
  // Handle degenerate cases.
  if (a == 0.0) {
    if (b == 0.0) {
      if (c == 0.0) {
        root[0] = root[1] = 0.0;
        return -1; // Infinite roots
      }
      root[0] = NAN;
      root[1] = NAN;
      return 0; // No roots
    }
    // Linear
    root[0] = -c / b;
    root[1] = NAN;
    return 1;
  }

  // 2 roots
  // roots = (-b +/- sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
  // //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Formulations_based_on_alternative_parametrizations
  double b_prime = -0.5 * b / a;
  double c_prime = c / a;

  // d = sqrt(b_prime*b_prime - c_prime)
  // r = b_prime +/- sqrt(d)
  double d;
  if (c_prime > 0) {
    double c_root = sqrt(c_prime);
    // d = b_prime*b_prime - c_root*c_root = (b_prime + c_root)*(b_prime - c_root)
    d = (b_prime - c_root) * (b_prime + c_root);
    if (d < 0) {  // complex root pair
      root[0] = b_prime + I * sqrt(-d);  // CMPLX(b_prime, sqrt(-d));
      root[1] = conj(root[0]);
      return 2;
    }
  } else {
    d = b_prime * b_prime - c_prime;
  }
  double d_prime = sqrt(d);
  if (b_prime > 0) {
    root[0] = b_prime + d_prime;
    root[1] = c_prime / creal(root[0]);
  } else if (b_prime < 0) {
    root[0] = b_prime + d_prime;
    root[1] = c_prime / creal(root[0]);
  } else {
    root[0] = d_prime;
    root[1] = -d_prime;
  }

  return 2;
}

